# Display portlets on search page in plone?

Tags: search, portlet, plone

How can I add portlets to a plone search or search results page?
Using @@manage-portlets doesn't work (www.mysite.com/search/@@manage-portlets), I get an empty search result. 
I'd like to display the portlets of the root folder also on that pages, in my case the search column uses the whole page width.

I'm using plone 4.0.1.

Answer (score 6):

Search results template has left and right portlet columns disabled (hidden):
http://dev.plone.org/plone/browser/Plone/tags/4.0.1/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_forms/search.pt#L19

If you want to display portlets there you should customize or override your `search.pt` template by removing the corresopnding line:

```
disable_column_one python:request.set('disable_plone.leftcolumn',1);
disable_column_two python:request.set('disable_plone.rightcolumn',1);
```

Anyway this will not let you set specific portlets for search results, as it's just a template opened in the Plone site root context. So you'll see Plone site root portlets.

The only way I think you could achieve that is:

1. Create a new special folder for search results (i.e. `search-results`).
2. Set your desired portlets in the new folder.
3. Set `search` as default page for that folder.
4. Modify search viewlet to redirect not to `/search` but to `/search-results`.
5. Modify `search_form` template (adavnced search) to redirect not to `/search` but to `/search-results`.

I did it once in a Plone 3 site and it worked. Although it wasn't to display special portlets.

Comment: doesn't work in plone 4.2, there is no more search.pt template in CMFPlone